# WP8 Nokia Here Maps: Get directions between two locations using official Here Maps app

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

I want to send two pairs of coordinates(my location and the destination) to Here Maps and show me the directions between those two locations without developing this of my own. Is this possible? If yes, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the [URI Association Schemes](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/wp-uri-schemes-for-location-applications/directions.html):

```
directions://v2.0/route/destination/?latlon=52.53,13.41&origin.latlon=52.53,13.41&mode=car
```

or the [HERE Launchers](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html):

```
DirectionsRouteDestinationTask routeTo = new DirectionsRouteDestinationTask();
routeTo.Destination = new GeoCoordinate(60.35, 24.60);
routeTo.Mode = RouteMode.Car;
routeTo.Show();
```

More information about these API [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html) and a demo application [here](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/here_launchers).

Comment: Actually, this is not working anymore on a newer version of Nokia Here Maps... any suggestions?